# How to capture PLAY and STOP event in Video.js player?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-player, video.js

I want to perform some actions on Play and Stop events. The Video.js [documentation](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-event-target.html) does talk about custom events but I am unable to figure out how to use it for play/stop when click the PLay/Stop Button

Comment: You might want to check the documentation API instead of the Guides section as provided in the link. Here's the API events link of the documentation: https://docs.videojs.com/module-events.html#.on

Comment: @savageGoat I have seen that, it is for custom event. Even if I create custom event I do not know how on click it would trigger. Do I need to inspect DOM and then bind event?

Comment: As said in the documentation and getting the event from it (https://docs.videojs.com/player#event:play), it should be something like `Play.on({}, "play", myTriggerHandlerFunctionHere)`

Answer (score 0):

```
player.on('play',()=>{});
player.on('pause',()=>{})
```

Above functions will track play and pause events in videojs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).